# Where is Request.CreateErrorResponse?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I saw it in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youssefm/archive/2012/06/28/error-handling-in-asp-net-webapi.aspx), but that doesn't actually say how to "enable" it. And it seems that by default it isn't enabled.

I know it's an extension method, as defined here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh835786(v=vs.108).aspx but how do I get access to it? If I type `Request.CreateErrorResponse` then the compiler doesn't recognize it.

I'm already `using System.Net.Http`.

Comment: Have you added references to the proper assemblies?

Comment: @SLaks: HttpRequestMessage. This is pretty much a scaffolded ApiController.

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson: I've got references to two of the three listed in the MSDN documentation, and the other "System.Web.Http.SelfHost" does not appear in the list when I choose "Add Reference". If that's the answer - and you know where to find it - put it in an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: What happens in IntelliSense if you type `HttpRequestMessageExtensions.`?

Comment: @SLaks: It goes blue / offers methods.

Comment: Then you really ought to be seeing the extension method too.  Can you check `My Solution` in Object Browser for version conflicts?

Comment: @SLaks: Sorry, you've lost me there. What am I looking for exactly? How would a conflict manifest itself?

Comment: @GaryMcGill: You would see the same assembly twice with two different versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you still using pre-release or release version?  There were a number of extensions that did not appear until just before the release and did not exist in earlier versions of the webapi release.  I am unsure if this was one of them, but it may be what is causing your problem.

Comment: I started off with the VS2012 RC and then upgraded my project. I don't know what effect that has under the scenes... Do you think I should start over?

Comment: I always start clean when moving from beta/rc releases to final public release but I can't tell you if that would solve your problem .  If you can see the method via ISense but it can't be seen when compiling, it could be a version conflict.  Do you have anything like .net reflector?  If you do, point it at the DLL that you are using and see if you can find System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessageExtensions and the extension method.  Also, I would only point to ONE of the DLLs mentioned, unless you are self-hosting, there is no reason to use the SelfHost.dll.

Comment: Thanks. I re-created my project from scratch, and the problem went away. Lots of _other_ things broke, but that problem is no more. :-)

Comment: Excellent, glad to hear it (except for the other things breaking).  Trying to upgrade betas and RCs are always a PIA.

Answer (score 46):

I've noticed this in release version as well.  And if you don't have the right using statement, it'll error.  You need :

```
using System.Net.Http;
```

even if you already have this:

```
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
```

Comment: `using System.Net.Http;` helps. Not sure why VS does not suggest to add it automatically.

Comment: Adding `using System.Web.Http.Controllers;` helped :)

Comment: @NikolaiSamteladze its because they are extensions and Visual Studio isn't clever enough to find these.

Answer (score 3):

Request is the public property of the ApiController class and should be available to you in any API actions in that controller.

```
public abstract class ApiController
{
   ...
   public HttpRequestMessage Request { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a small code sample that works for me:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;


public class MyFirstApiController : ApiController
{
    // GET 
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed, "Some   message here");
    }
}
```

Interestingly enough, if I take away using System.Net.Http; statement, Request no longer has a CreateErrorResponse() method.

Comment: Thanks... Indeed it should. But it wasn't. Resolved now though - see accepted answer.

Comment: I am not sure what the point of the second parameter is (in your case "Some   message here") as it does not appear anywhere in the HttpResponseMessage.

Answer (score 2):

Although important points have been answered.

One more dumbest possibility is that you might have chosen wrong type of controller.
Make sure you have created an **Web API controller**, incase of MVC controller you cannot have

```
Request.CreateErrorResponse()
```

Just another possibility where you may find this issue.

Answer (score 2):

In .net core, add `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim.dll` .

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httprequestmessageextensions.createerrorresponse?view=aspnetcore-2.0

Answer (score 0):

Use **System.Web.Http** assembly.
source: [CreateErrorResponse Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessageextensions.createerrorresponse(v=vs.118).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use from that In block Try-Catch.

 [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage DownloadVideo(Guid id, string title)
    {
        try
        {
          //Your Code at the end return result
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think you misunderstood the issue. The `CreateErrorResponse` method was not defined, perhaps due to the assembly that contains the extension method not being referenced.

Answer (score 0):

Inject and instance of the HttpRequestMessage in your controller constructor or method:

```
Task<ActionResult<GetOneShopDtoResponse>> GetOne(HttpRequestMessage request,int shopId) {
    return request.CreateErrorResponse(.....)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

My best guess is that it is the third assembly, that you haven't referenced, that is the problem.

Unfortunately I don't have access to my computer, browsing on my phone, so I can't track down the file for you. According to the docs it should be in System.Web.Http.SelfHost.dll, so I guess you could just search for that file to locate it.