# Modify API response before passing back to controller in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm able to achieve same behavior easily in .NET Framework but coming to .NET Core I don't find needed methods to achieve same

*Snippet:* below **response** has only Getter no setter and CreateErrorResponse is not supported

```
var error = new HttpError
        {
           {
             "data", reqdInfo
           }
        };

context.Response = context.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, error);
```

I want to include above error info in the response before i give back control to controller

Edit: In framework

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is Request.CreateErrorResponse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555795/where-is-request-createerrorresponse)

Comment: not entirely @MattEvans . say even I've CreateErrorResponse still i cannot assign this to the context.reponse as it dont have setter

Comment: Can you please specify what actual behaviour you are trying to achieve and what is "the same"?

Comment: @GuruStron edited: if u see above code i'm able to set context.response by creating new error response but in .net core not sure how i can do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET was heavily reworked since the pre-.NET Core version. Something potentially similar can be achieved with `Results` class (available since ASP.NET Core 6). For example:

```cs
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (context.Request.Path.Value.Equals("/api/test/error", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        await Results.Problem(new ProblemDetails
            {
                Extensions = { { "data", new { Value = 1 } } }
            })
            .ExecuteAsync(context);
    }
    else
    {
        await next();
    }
});
```

Which produces the following result for `/api/test/error`:

```json
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.6.1",
    "title": "An error occurred while processing your request.",
    "status": 500,
    "data": {
        "value": 1
    }
}
```

Potentially useful articles:

1. [Handle errors in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-7.0)
2. [Handle errors in ASP.NET Core web APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-7.0)
3. [Write custom ASP.NET Core middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: is there a way we can write a custom middleware actionexecuting of action filter ?

Comment: @supercool in short - yes. In more details - depends on actual use case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75611997/unable-to-return-exception-details-using-exceptionfilterattribute maybe your view might help here