# Unable to return exception details using ExceptionFilterAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I've a need to write exception filter for couple of controllers in .NET 6 and for that i've written below and when i do a postman i always get Error: Aborted which is weird

**Code:**

```
public class TestFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override async void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        var info = { } //serialized object
        context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "appication/json";
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 400;
        await context.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync(info);
    }
}
```

**Registered:**

```
services.AddSingleton<TestFilterAttribute>();
```

Decorated [TestFilter] on my api controller when i intentionally throw exception to check, i always get site cannot be reached. Same logic i've tried in middleware i properly get response in json with expected status code

Comment: What if you try to flush the response before writing to it?

Comment: currently making using of IActionfilter & .result combi to work around it as it short circuits pipeline just like  flushing out response as u mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-6.0#exception-filters) related

You could try as below:

```
public class TestFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override async void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
        {
            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(someobj);
           
           
        }
    }
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

Since you're trying with an attribute,you don't have to regist it in IServiceCollection

```
services.AddSingleton<TestFilterAttribute>();
```

You could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.objectresult?view=aspnetcore-7.0) about child classes of ObjectResult

Comment: smart answer! I'm kindoff using the same cheers :)

Comment: can u elaborate why we don't need in iservicecollection

Comment: Just because you were trying with C# attribute not dependency injection